# Pig installation not working

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have installed Pig 0.12.0 on my box. I have also installed Java and Hadoop and have set JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME paths. When Igo to the bin directory of pig installation and type the following command on my command prompt:

> pig -help

it errors out with the following message:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
'-Xmx1000M' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Whats wrong?
Should I be using cygwin? (that didnt work either)

Comment: Can you share any modifications you made to pig, and how you installed it?

Answer (score 2):

I just installed Pig 0.12.1 on Windows 7 without Hadoop installed.  I also got this error message and resolved it by setting the "JAVA" environment variable to point to the java.exe executable.

In my case, I set `JAVA=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe`

I also set:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
PIG_HOME=C:\pig-0.12.1  (This is where I extracted pig-0.12.1.tar.gz)
```

and added `C:\pig-0.12.1\bin` to my `PATH` environment variable.

Hope this helps anyone else with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late reply, but hope this will help someone to configure pig

**Using OS Windows 8.1 ProN x64**

Note -> Life will be easier in configuration, if your directory path doesn't contains a whitespace.

**Steps to configure Pig with Hadoop**

**java path location (jdk1.8.0_151)**

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
```

**python path location (Python27)**

```
C:\Python27
```

**ant path location (apache-ant-1.10.1)**

```
ANT_HOME F:\Hadoop\apache-ant-1.10.1
```

**hadoop path location (hadoop-2.8.2)**

```
HADOOP_HOME F:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.8.2

HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR %HADOOP_HOME%\lib\native

HADOOP_CONF_DIR %HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop
```

**pig path location (pig-0.17.0)**

```
PIG_HOME F:\Hadoop\pig-0.17.0
```

**System Variables Path**

`C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;F:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.8.2\bin;F:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.8.2\sbin;F:\Hadoop\pig-0.17.0\bin;`

1. explore `winutils-master.zip` on `github`, pull and download, extract to `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` directory
2. open `%PIG_HOME%\bin\pig.cmd` using notepad/notepad++ (recommended notepad++)
3. change the below said line and later save it, close it -

   "`set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`" to 
   "`set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=%HADOOP_HOME%\libexec`"
4. so now the pig will access `hadoop-config.cmd` inside `%HADOOP_HOME%` path as we configured earlier.
5. `start-all.cmd` from hadoop to start the cluster with all dependencies.
6. go to `%PIG_HOME%/bin`, check with `pig -help` (if results are as parameterized).
7. `pig` (Enter to `grunt` shell.)

Note -> there are much possibilities to get below exception, if you don't configure as above.

```
'F:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.8.2\bin\hadoop-config.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 

'-Xmx1000M' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

hope, these illustrated steps will help you to configure and start the pig grunt shell, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
This will solve your problem...

1.Download PIG ->http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/pig/pig-0.16.0/    
2.Set properties->    
  PIG_HOME=C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\pig-0.16.0\pig-0.16.0    
  path=C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\pig-0.16.0\pig-0.16.0\bin    
  PIG_CLASSPATH=C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\hadoop-2.7.3\hadoop-2.7.3\etc\hadoop(Where 
                core-site.xml,mapred-site.xml are present)    
3.    
  ->open the file pig.cmd(From bin directory of PIG)   
  ->look for the line set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=%HADOOP_HOME%\bin    
  ->replace this with set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=%HADOOP_HOME%\libexec    
4.Now in command prompt give->pig    `enter code here`
```